# Using values_list and extra on same queryset

Tags: django

I have some existing code that calls values_list on a queryset. I need to add something using extra to this queryset. If I call extra before values_list the extra stuff is gone from the query after the values_list. If I call extra after the call to values_list it seems to have to effect - the extra stuff is not in the query.

Here is some debugger output. extra before values_list - it's there then gone:

```
-> queryset = queryset.extra(select={field['name'] : field['name']})
(Pdb) n
-> queryset = queryset.values_list(*self.get_search_columns())
(Pdb) print queryset.query
SELECT (top-bottom) AS `top-bottom`,  ....
(Pdb) n
-> data = list(queryset)
(Pdb) print queryset.query
SELECT `data_cst`.`image_measurer_id`, `data_cst`.`image_pr_top_id`,
`data_target`.`name`, `data_recipe`.`name`, `data_cst`.`ep`,
`data_lot`.`name`, `data_cst`.`date_time`, `data_cst`.`bottom` FROM
`data_cst` INNER JOIN `data_target` ON (`data_cst`.`target_name_id` =
`data_target`.`id`) INNER JOIN `data_recipe` ON
(`data_cst`.`recipe_id` = `data_recipe`.`id`) INNER JOIN `data_lot` ON
(`data_cst`.`lot_id` = `data_lot`.`id`) WHERE (`data_cst`.`date_time`
<= 2013-03-26 23:59:59  AND `data_cst`.`date_time` >= 2010-03-26
00:00:00 ) ORDER BY `data_cst`.`date_time` DESC
```

But if I reverse the order the extra doesn't make to the query at all:

```
-> queryset = queryset.values_list(*self.get_search_columns())
(Pdb) n
-> queryset = queryset.extra(select={field['name'] : field['name']})
(Pdb) print queryset.query
SELECT `data_cst`.`image_measurer_id`, `data_cst`.`image_pr_top_id`,
`data_target`.`name`, `data_recipe`.`name`, `data_cst`.`ep`,
`data_lot`.`name`, `data_cst`.`date_time`, `data_cst`.`bottom` FROM
`data_cst` INNER JOIN `data_target` ON (`data_cst`.`target_name_id` =
`data_target`.`id`) INNER JOIN `data_recipe` ON
(`data_cst`.`recipe_id` = `data_recipe`.`id`) INNER JOIN `data_lot` ON
(`data_cst`.`lot_id` = `data_lot`.`id`) WHERE (`data_cst`.`date_time`
<= 2013-03-26 23:59:59  AND `data_cst`.`date_time` >= 2010-03-26
00:00:00 ) ORDER BY `data_cst`.`date_time` DESC
{Pdb) n
-> data = list(queryset)
(Pdb) print queryset.query
SELECT `data_cst`.`image_measurer_id`, `data_cst`.`image_pr_top_id`,
`data_target`.`name`, `data_recipe`.`name`, `data_cst`.`ep`,
`data_lot`.`name`, `data_cst`.`date_time`, `data_cst`.`bottom` FROM
`data_cst` INNER JOIN `data_target` ON (`data_cst`.`target_name_id` =
`data_target`.`id`) INNER JOIN `data_recipe` ON
(`data_cst`.`recipe_id` = `data_recipe`.`id`) INNER JOIN `data_lot` ON
(`data_cst`.`lot_id` = `data_lot`.`id`) WHERE (`data_cst`.`date_time`
<= 2013-03-26 23:59:59  AND `data_cst`.`date_time` >= 2010-03-26
00:00:00 ) ORDER BY `data_cst`.`date_time` DESC
```

Is there some way to use both values_list and extra on same queryset?

Here's a very simple example showing it's not working:

```
(Pdb) CST.objects.all().extra(select={'ep': 1}).values_list('image_measurer_id')
[(86456L,), (86454L,), (86452L,), (86450L,), (86448L,), (86446L,),
(86444L,), (86442L,), (86440L,), (86438L,), (86436L,), (86434L,),
(86432L,), (86430L,), (86428L,), (86426L,), (86424L,), (86422L,),
(86420L,), (86418L,), '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

This should return 2 columns per row.

Comment: The information you've provided doesn't make it easy to help you. Provide info from outside of PDB, document the class that you're in and what `fields['name']` is

Comment: Just updated my post with a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to include your extra select in the values_list.

E.g.

```
CST.objects.extra(select={'ep': 1}).values_list('image_measurer_id','ep')
```